# Android low quality Bitmap from RelativeLayout View containing MapView

Tags: android, view, bitmap, screenshot, android-relativelayout

I am producing a Bitmap from a RelativeLayout that contains another Bitmap from a MapView set as the background plus two other views (icon & text) in the right hand corner. I'm getting the image I want but it is low quality. I've search high and low and found many pages on converting Views to Bitmaps but nothing regarding quality. I'm guessing it might be something to do with scaling.

The output image:

[image: output image low quality]

The code:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromMapView() {
    // Get Bitmap from MapView
    Bitmap mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMapView.getWidth(), mMapView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mapCanvas = new Canvas(mapBitmap);
    mMapView.draw(mapCanvas);

    // Inflate RelativeLayout view containing ImageView (FlagIt icon) and TextView (URL) in bottom-right corner
    // and merge it with the MapView Bitmap to produce an Overall Bitmap containing everything
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout overallRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.screenshot, null);
    overallRelativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mapBitmap));

    overallRelativeLayout.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapView.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    overallRelativeLayout.layout(0, 0, overallRelativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), overallRelativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap overallBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMapView.getWidth(), mMapView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas overallCanvas = new Canvas(overallBitmap);
    overallRelativeLayout.draw(overallCanvas);


    return overallBitmap;
}
```

and the inflated screenshot.xml XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screenshot_corner_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="0.0"
        android:shadowDy="0.0"
        android:shadowRadius="4"
        android:text="http://www.aroha.ws"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/screenshot_corner_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/screenshot_corner_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/corner_title_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout when displayed on my screen looks better quality:

[output image desired quality http://5312208804164438257-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/arohacorp/pilcrowpipeblog/device-2012-04-20-224931.png](http://5312208804164438257-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/arohacorp/pilcrowpipeblog/device-2012-04-20-224931.png)